# Navigation between ContentViews Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm working on the navegation of my app. I need to have total control of the navigation, let the user goback only when I want him to do it, control what page he is going back, maybe the last page or maybe the main menu or other page between those. For me the easy way to control this is using this actions:

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new NotAccesableGoBackPage(), this);
Navigation.PopAsync(false);

Navigation.PushAsync(new AccesableGoBackPage());

App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new DestroyNavigationStack());
```

By combining those I hace the total control of my navigation. Now my issue. I want to have allways a header, control buttons and footer template sharing between my pages. I read and I found that I need to use ContentView for the template and ContentPage for the body. But by using ContentsView I can't use the Navigation that I'm using.

How could I solve this problem? Some recomendation? Thank you.

EDIT:

This is my template. It has the header, buttons and footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/xamarin/2014/forms/editors"
             x:Class="NoguianaNucleo.Views.ContainerPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Header -->
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <!--Body -->
            <RowDefinition Height="24*"/>
            <!--Buttons -->
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <!--Footer -->
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Header -->
        <Label x:Name="lbl_title" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <!--Body -->
        <Grid x:Name="body_grid" Grid.Row="1" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
        <!--Buttons -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="#C8A2C8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--B1 -->
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <!--B2 -->
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--B1 -->
            <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_1" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <!--B2 -->
            <dxe:SimpleButton x:Name="btn_2" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <!--Footer -->
        <Label x:Name="lbl_footer" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

This is my C# control for the template:

```
public partial class ContainerPage : ContentPage {
    public ContainerPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbl_footer.Text = "Footer";
    }
}
```

This is the content of my body (XAML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:ContainerPage  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NoguianaNucleo.Views"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NoguianaNucleo.Views.Gestion.ConsultationEmplacementPage">

</views:ContainerPage>
```

Y the C# of the body:

```
public ConsultationEmplacementPage() {
    InitializeComponent();

    //Title
    lbl_title.Text = "Lorem ipsu...";

    //Text
    Label info = new Label();
    info.Text = "Lorem ipsu...";

    body_grid.Children.Add(info, 0, 0);
    body_grid.Children.Add(barcode, 0, 1);

    btn_2.Icon = "Back.png";
    btn_2.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
        btn_4.IconColor = Utilities.black;
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    };
}
```

How could I do this last code on XAML and insert into the `body_grid` of the template?

Comment: create a base page containing the header and footer view, and then each of your ContentPages can inherit from that base page

Comment: I alrady have this configuration. It is working fine but I have to complet the body by programability on C# not by XAML. Using C# for the front-end is a tough work. Any other idea?

Comment: Everything I suggested could be done in c#.  XAML is not a requirement

Comment: How could I code de XAML body from the children? I am going to add my code to the post

Comment: See [Control Template, section: Substitute content into a ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter).

Comment: @Jason -  Inheriting from a base page - how do you inject the page-specific content between the header and footer of the base page? Need more details about that approach. Regardless, I've added link to the recommended solution, which is to use Control Template and a ContentPresenter. Presumably the base-page approach also uses a ContentPresenter, or similar sub-element.

Comment: When I use ´ContentPresenter´ on my header and footer XAML, the body code fill all the screen and overlaps the header and footer. When I create and add a ´ControlTemplate´ I lose the control of my labels and bottons of the header and footer. What could I do? I would like to add this template to the App because I want to use it for all my app. Thank you

Comment: @DavidZarzosoMoreno Maybe you can take a look [Substitute content into a ContentPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template#substitute-content-into-a-contentpresenter)